# How to get username input from Windows Authentication in IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, windows-server-2008

In IIS I have the authentication set to Windows.

2 Questions:

1. Is there a way that I can grab the username that was entered by the user for that pop-up authentication window before it loads the page and
2. Is there a way I can make it so that the login is required every time they visit the page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question this is how you access the user from a windows authentication:

```
WindowsPrincipal winPrincipal = (WindowsPrincipal)HttpContext.Current.User;
```

There are other options like:

```
WindowsIdentity winId = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
WindowsPrincipal winPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(winId);
```

Or

```
WindowsPrincipal winPrincipal = (WindowsPrincipal) Thread.CurrentPrincipal();
```

Comment: Can anyone of the principals or contexts get the password?

Comment: No, password is not retried and this is for security reasons.

Comment: Okay. It also seems to me like as long as the user logged in at least once then before their session ends it will always show the context for the most recent login. This should be fine as I was just trying to avoid the username of the process running the default app pool from being returned for archival purposes.

Comment: If that is your concern this is subject or [Authorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d82143t(v=vs.85).aspx) and can be resolved in the web.config by using the authorization config element like: `<authorization><allow roles="Admins"/><deny users="*"/></authorization>`